# Why isn't my onclick function activating when I press the button?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm changing over from Java to Javascript as I'd like to expand my programming capabilities, and I'm not sure why but I'm having a really hard time adjusting. For example, I'm not even sure why I can't get the Javascript function to run, nevermind actually work the way I want it to.

I feel like I might not have the JS wired up to my HTML document properly, but I have included the correct filename within a script tag, and the two files are within the same folder, so why isn't the JS function even being called?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <!-- Basic Page Needs
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>To-do Webapp</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <!-- Mobile Specific Metas
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- FONT
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <!--<link href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,300,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->

  <!-- CSS
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/skeleton.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styling.css">
  </head>

  <!-- scripts
  –––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––– -->
<script src="script.js"></script>


<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 15%">
        <h2>To-do Webapp</h4>
        <p>Enter your task into the box below.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="ten columns">
          <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="inputtask" placeholder="Enter a task"/>
        </div>
        <div class="two columns">
          <!-- <input class="button" onclick="addTask()" value="Add task"> -->
          <button onclick="addTask()">Button element</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

JS

```
function addTask() {
    "use strict";
    /*global document: false */
    document.alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: As a rule of thumb, never use inline javascript. Attach [eventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead.

Comment: `<script src="script.js"></script>` needs to be in either the head or the body, to be valid.

Comment: @bambam So do I getElementById to get the button, then attach an event listener to it outside of any function?

Comment: To avoid this sort of trivial issues use dev console in browser and debugger

Comment: Don't listen to @bambam, it's fine to use inline javascript... but press f12 to see if there's an error in the console... chances are you'll see "document.alert is not a function"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is `window.alert("hello");`, not `document.alert("hello");`

*And inline script is not recommended, use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead*

Stack snippet

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addTask);

});


function addTask() {
  "use strict";
  /*global document: false */
  window.alert("hello");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 15%">
      <h2>To-do Webapp</h4>
        <p>Enter your task into the box below.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ten columns">
        <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="inputtask" placeholder="Enter a task" />
      </div>
      <div class="two columns">
        <!-- <input class="button" onclick="addTask()" value="Add task"> -->
        <button>Button element</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

Note, the line adding the event listener needs to be called after DOM loaded, as seen in above code sample, or in a script at the end of the `body`, as shown in below sample.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="one-half column" style="margin-top: 15%">
      <h2>To-do Webapp</h4>
        <p>Enter your task into the box below.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="ten columns">
        <input class="u-full-width" type="text" id="inputtask" placeholder="Enter a task" />
      </div>
      <div class="two columns">
        <!-- <input class="button" onclick="addTask()" value="Add task"> -->
        <button>Button element</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', addTask);

  function addTask() {
    "use strict";
    /*global document: false */
    window.alert("hello");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I knew it would be something simple. Urgh. Thank you.

Comment: also, you aren't closing your container div before the `</body>` tag

Comment: @ps2goat Fixed the tag issue in my sample